# Ruby require not finding all files

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've done some research and nothing quite hits on my issue...

I'm building a gem so I have a directory structure like this

```
root/ - lib/ - mygem/   - cli.rb
                        - version.rb
                        - xmltemplates.rb
             - mygem.rb
      - bin/
```

It's a `thor` app so in `cli.rb` I have:

```
require 'thor'
require 'mygem/version'
require 'mygem/xmltemplates'

module MyGem
    #STUFF
end
```

And in `vesrion.rb`:

```
module MyGem
    VERSION = '0.1.0'
end
```

and in `xmltemplates.rb`:

```
module MyGem
    MY_TEMPLATE = 'TEST'
end
```

I was getting errors when trying to compile with as a gem so I decided to play with it in irb.

So for this test I did `cd lib` to make myself local to the lib directory.

```
1.9.3-p392 :001 > require 'rubygems'
 => false
1.9.3-p392 :003 > require 'mygem'
 => true
1.9.3-p392 :005 > require 'mygem/cli'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mygem/xmltemplates
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mygem-0.1.0/lib/mygem/cli.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):5
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p392 :007 > require 'mygem/xmltemplates'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mygem/xmltemplates
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):7
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p392 :009 > require 'mygem/version'
 => true
1.9.3-p392 :010 > MyGem::VERSION
 => "0.1.0"
```

So it boils down to this: Is there any reason that `mygem/version` would load find and `mygem.xmltemplates` would not? I've checked permissions on the files as well and they are all identical.

Some of the previous posts I've read mentioned `require_relative`, but that didn't work for me and it seems like if that was it I would not have been able to load `cli.rb` or `version.rb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with gems it's important that your `.gemspec` file is up to date. The gem loader uses this to find files. Perhaps you haven't added `xmltemplates` to that spec yet?

If you're trying to diagnose loading problems, always check `$LOAD_PATH` to be sure your `lib/` is in there. If it isn't, you will get `LoadError` type exceptions due to missing files.

Comment: My gemspec shows:

`s.require_paths = ['lib']`

You were on to it though!!!

Just realized I also had this: `s.files = 'git ls-files'.split("\n")`. It was a copy paste job so I didn't think to change it. I guess I had to `git add` for it to work. Thanks for the point in the right direction!

Comment: That's exactly it. If something's not listed in the manifest, it doesn't get bundled and installed.